# AppendRow Column Offset

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I wrote a Google Sheets Apps Script to function as a data entry form for my team to use. The script works great, but I'm looking for a way to improve it. I'd like to be able to skip the first column in the sheet where the entry line gets dropped into ("Archive" sheet). So the data would get dropped starting in Column 2 instead of Column 1. How do I make the AppendRow offset over by one column in this way?

```
function Entry() {  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  var result = ui.alert(  
    'Please only log this data when you have finished the brew',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);  
    if(result == ui.Button.YES) {  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
      var ent = ss.getSheetByName("Form Entry");  
      var prev = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");  
      var copy = ent.getRange('I3:AZ3');  
      prev.appendRow(copy.getValues()[0]);  
      var rangelist = ent.getRangeList(['C4','C6:C13','B18:D27','B29']).clearContent();  
      return  
      
  } else {  
    return;  
  }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct an array that starts with an extra blank value, and get the values in `copy` using spread syntax, like this:

```
      prev.appendRow([null, ...copy.getValues().flat()]);
```

See [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

In the event you have values or formulas in other columns in the `prev` sheet, and always want to write after the last value in column `B` regardless of what is in the other columns, use the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function, like this:

```
      appendRows_(prev, copy.getValues(), 2);
```